# Java 8 Stream - Compiler Issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I was casually working on one of my projects in my IDE, IntelliJ. It didn't show any errors at all, but as soon as I compiled, an error popped up which didn't allow me to build the project.

I first tried to update my JDK, because I was still on Update 65. I updated to the latest available version (which was u101 at the time) with no luck: The issue was still there. This is the related code:

```
((List<?>) value).stream().filter(this::isStringOrPrimitive)
                            .map(val -> getCommandHandler(command, plugin, val.toString()))
                            .forEach(result::add);
```

The code that wasn't compiling was the part surrounding .forEach(result::add). Result is declared and initialized in this line:

```
List<CommandHandler> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

And the getCommandHandler method's descriptor:

```
private <T, C> CommandHandler getCommandHandler(Command<T, C> command,
                                                AnimatedMenuPlugin plugin, String str) {
```

The error that occured while compiling:

```
Error:(59, 42) java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.Collection.add(me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler)
    method java.util.List.add(me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler)
    method java.util.AbstractCollection.add(me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler)
    method java.util.AbstractList.add(me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler)
    method java.util.ArrayList.add(me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to me.megamichiel.animatedmenu.command.CommandExecutor.CommandHandler)
```

I tried several things to see if it would affect anything:

- Map the stream using a cast (CommandHandler.class::cast), didn't fix the issue
- Remove the method reference, and replace it with a normal method call (val -> result.add(val)). Also didn't fix it
- As a final option, I used the method call and casted val to CommandHandler. This fixed the issue, but I did not like that I had to manually cast to CommandHandler while Java could do it themselves.

I could also completely get rid of the stream, but I want to first see if this is some sort of compiler issue, or if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try using explicit parameter types in your lambdas and explicit type parameters with your generic methods. Then remove them one at a time to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird compiler behavior. Try to extract initial stream and provide a type parameter `?`.

```
Stream<?> stream = ((List<?>) value).stream();
stream.filter(this::isStringOrPrimitive)
    .map(val -> getCommandHandler(command, plugin, val.toString()))
    .forEach(result::add);
```

For my code it helped compiler to properly infer type of other steps in pipeline.

Comment: I first tried this, but it unfortunately didn't solve the problem. I did use your idea of externalizing though to make the variable a Stream<CommandHandler> and went all the way until after the mapping. Then calling .forEach on the variable did fix it, thanks for the guidelines!